# How to execute search query in multiple sub sites of WordPress multisite website's root site?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Consider my WordPress multisite has the following four websites:

1. root/main website: `example-domain.com`
2. subsite 1: `example-domain.com/en`
3. subsite 2: `example-domain.com/cn`
4. subsite 3: `example-domain.com/ar`

When a user searches for anything in the root site I want to search/query in all of the websites and display.

Do I have to use the `switch_to_blog( $site_id );` function to switch sites one by one to search/query the tables of the website? or any other way to query all the `posts` tables that exist for the multisite network?